# Can't manipulate files that were saved using carrierwave gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I am getting the following message when i try to manipulate a file that i have stored in the database using carrierwave:

```
NoMethodError in DataFilesController#show
private method `gets' called for /files/test_file.csv:CsvFileUploader
```

Here some model code where the error is originating:

```
 def self.csv_import(file_wrapper, event_id)
    event = Event.find(event_id)
    file = file_wrapper.filename
    header = file.gets.strip

    keys = header.split(',')

    while (line = file.gets)
      params = {}
      values = line.strip.split(',')

      keys.each_with_index do |key,i|
        params[key] = values[i]
      end

      volunteer = event.volunteers.build(params)
      volunteer.save

    end
  end
```

Here is my model where i mount the carrierwave file:

```
class DataFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :attachable_id, :attachable_type, :filename
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
  mount_uploader :filename, CsvFileUploader
end
```

Here is the controller code:

```
def create
    @event = Event.find(session[:stored_event_id].to_i)
    session[:stored_event_id] = @event.id
    @file = @event.data_files.build(params[:data_file])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @file.save
        format.html { redirect_to data_files_path(@event_id)}
        format.json { render json: @file, status: :created, location: @file }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @file.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Basically I have a model called Events that has a polymorphic relationship with a model called DataFile.  The DataFile model has a attribute called 'filename' that has carrierwave  uploader mounted to it.

Thanks